# How to change auto-increment initial value using Web2py and MySQL

Tags: mysql, web2py

I am using web2py with mysql to build a database which aims to record the number of entries (like shipping order) together with the date.

For example, today is Mar 10 2014, and there are already 4 orders received. Upon creating a new order, the new order number is expected to be **20140310005**.

I figured I can use the auto-increment field in mysql to do this. I can auto deploy a code that set the auto-increment to the date everyday, say tomorrow Mar 11 to be **20140311001**.

The question is, how can I change the auto-increment initial value in Web2py?

Comment: Bad idea that, you do not want to do this. What is this number used for. Think what happens if someone deletes / unreceives this order. How are you going to deal with transactions that span midnight. How are you going to deal with multiple transactions. World of hurt, waiting to hurt you this.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with comment from Tony Hopkinson, but it is possible (with a myisam table) to do like this:

```
create table weborder(order_date date not null, 
        order_sequence int not null auto_increment, 
        primary key(order_date, order_sequence)) engine=myisam;
insert into weborder values('2014-03-10', null);
insert into weborder values('2014-03-10', null);
insert into weborder values('2014-03-10', null);
insert into weborder values('2014-03-11', null);
select * from weborder;
```

and your data will look like this:

```
"order_date"    "order_sequence"
"2014-03-10"    "1"
"2014-03-10"    "2"
"2014-03-10"    "3"
"2014-03-11"    "1"
```